# Best intersection of a collection of line segments?

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry, computational-geometry

I have a number of 2D line segments that should all intersect at one point but don't because of noise earlier in the calculations that cannot be reduced.

Is there an algorithm to compute the best approximation to the intersection of all the line segments. Something like the point with the minimum average distance to all the line segments that doesn't necessarily lie on any of the segments?

Comment: What's wrong with simple average of all intersections? If it is OK, it is simple and straight forward, you should use it. If not - please describe what's the problem with it - it will help us understand your problem better.

Comment: If the intersection must lie on one of the segments, then the intersection closed to the mean of intersections might be a good bet.

Comment: @amit Agreed. And proof that the average of the intersections minimizes the average distance to the intersections is given in my answer below.

Comment: @amit is correct, but you don't have to compute all the pairwise intersections. You can formulate this as a least-squares problem, where you are looking for a point that is closest to all the lines supporting the segments. This has linear complexity in the number of segments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have freedom to select a metric, sum of squared distances may give a simple algorithm.

We can represent square of distance to a line #i as function of point coordinates, we will get `(A[i]x,x)+(b[i],x)+c[i]`, `A[i]` is a matrix 3x3, `b[i]` - vector, `c[i]` - number, (a,b) - scalar multiplication.

Their sum will be `(A[sum]x,x)+(b[sum],x)+c[sum]`.

Minimum of such function is `x=-inverse(A[sum])b[sum]/2`.

Answer (score 3):

The first comment from Amit is your answer. I'll explain why.

Let `p_i` be your points of intersection and `c = 1/n sum(p_i)`. Let's show that `c` minimizes the average distance, `d(a)` between the `p_i` and an arbitrary point `a`:

```
d(a) = 1/n sum( |a-p_i|^2 )
```

What is being averaged in `d(a)` is, using inner product notation,

```
|a-p_i|^2 = <a-p_i, a-p_i> = |a|^2 + |p_i|^2 - 2<a,p_i>`
```

The average of `<a,p_i>` is just `<a,c>`, using the bilinear properties of dot product. So,

```
d(a) = |a|^2 - 2<a,c> + 1/n sum( |p_i|^2 )
```

And so likewise

```
d(c) = |c|^2 - 2<c,c> + 1/n sum( |p_i|^2 ) = -|c|^2 + 1/n sum( |p_i|^2 )
```

Subtracting the two

```
d(a) - d(c) = |a|^2 - 2<a,c> + |c|^2 = |a-c|^2
```

So, adding `d(c)` to both sides, the average distance to an arbitrary point `a` is

```
d(a) = d(c) + |a-c|^2
```

which since all terms are positive is minimized when `|a-c|^2` is zero, in other words, when `a = c`.